# COD 4 crashes on my desktop during mission 'Shock and Awe'

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

When I am on the mission 'Shock and Awe' in Call of Duty 4 the plane crashes and I regain my conscience in game and I look around. Then I fall down and the game crashes.

I have encountered this problem on both my desktop (Windows 7 32 bit) and my laptop (Windows 8). I didn't understand what to do so I did nothing.

Comment: Try adjusting your visual settings and see if that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try To re-install the game....

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer. While reinstalling might fix the problem, it doesn't explain why it would.